# How to make EF core 6 correctly store derived types with Cosmos DB provider?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have an entity

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public ObjectNode Node;
}
```

`ObjectNode` is the base class for specific nodes:

```
public class ObjectNode
{
  public string NodeType {get; set;}
  public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then, there are various subclasses of `ObjectNode`, for example:

```
public class DocumentNode : ObjectNode
{
  public string Path { get; set;}
}
```

I configure:
`modelBuilder.HasDefaultContainer("MyEntity");`

I create a `MyEntity` instance like this:

```
var ent = new MyEntity {
  Id = "entity1",
  Node = new DocumentNode {
      Id = "node1",
      NodeType = "Document"
      Path = "some document path"
  }
};
```

When storing it in Cosmos DB, the result is:

```json
{
  "Id" : "entity1",
  "Node" : {
      "Id" : "node1",
      "NodeType" : "Document"
   }
  ]
}
```

The `Path` property doesn't show up and when deserializing, I'm getting back an `ObjectNode` instead of a `DocumentNode`.

Only by changing `NodeType Node` to `Document Node` in my model, would I get all properties. But obviously then it won't work for other derived types.

How can this behavior be fixed?
I tried to declare `DocumentNode` as an entity using `modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentNode>`, but that yields a runtime error about a missing partition key property - which is right, as I don't want this to be stored as a separate document but just as a nested element.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm deep in this thing now xD

Comment: Unfortunately, no.