# CosmosDB EF Core 8 derived type configuration

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to use a common base class for a collection in cosmosdb and query it via EF Core 8. The general idea is that my entities will be similar and have a common base but be able to add new properties.

My problem is, this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307933/how-to-make-ef-core-6-correctly-store-derived-types-with-cosmos-db-provider), how to correctly define the derived types from their base and have the model builder happy with it and not footgun myself when I want to add several more variations of the theme.

Dependencies for project

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Host (just a console one)

```
using CosEF.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

HostBuilder builder = new();

builder.ConfigureDefaults(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CosmosContext>(options =>
        {
            // this is the fixed emulator account key, its not a real one.
            options.UseCosmos("AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==", "mydb");
        });
    });

IHost host = builder.Build();

CosmosContext ctxt = host.Services.GetRequiredService<CosmosContext>();

// example 'seed'
ctxt.Animals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "chopper", Lives = 4, Family = "cats", Id = 3 });
await ctxt.SaveChangesAsync();

IEnumerable<Cat> cats = await ctxt.GetAnimalsAsync<Cat>();
```

DB Context / Models

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CosEF.Data
{
    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public required string Family { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string Breed { get; set; } = "Misc";
    }

    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        public int Lives { get; set; } = 9;
        public Embed Embedded { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class  Embed
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; } = "this is an embedded document";
    }

    public class CosmosContext(DbContextOptions<CosmosContext> options) : DbContext(options)
    {
        public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultContainer("animals");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>()
                .HasPartitionKey(s => s.Family)
                .HasKey(s => s.Id);

            // this is the part i'm not sure about
            modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>();//.HasPartitionKey(s => s.Family);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>();//.HasPartitionKey(s => s.Family);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAnimalsAsync<T>() where T : Animal
            => await this.Animals.OfType<T>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

The exception I get when trying to operate on these types is

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Cat' does not have a partition key set, but is mapped to the container 'animals' shared by entity types with partition keys. Configure a compatible partition key on 'Cat'

What is the right approach for setup up the Entities so one container can just hold a set of documents for similar things? I can make this work if I use the same `HasPartitionKey()` builder extension to all my derived types but this feels potentially error prone and unnecessary. If I set the entity partition key to another string property it refuses to run the query complaining about mismatched keys, which seems fair. Is there ever a case where you'd somehow want to define a different partition key for an entity within the same container - I wouldn't expect this ever works?

So, what is the right approach for derived types with EF and cosmos? The e2e example in the EF docs doesn't use any type discriminators and the TPT, TPCT and whatever from the relational world don't seem appropriate here?